# How can INSERT INTO a table N times within a loop in SQL Server using a concatenated ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, recursive-query

I would like to insert a concatenated id in SQL SERVER and repeat it N times.

Actually i have something like this:

```
DECLARE @COUNT INT;
DECLARE @NUM_INSERTS INT;
SET @COUNT = 1;
SET @NUM_INSERTS = 10;

WHILE (@COUNT <= @NUM_INSERTS)
BEGIN
   DECLARE @randomID VARCHAR(2);  
   SET @randomID = CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 10) AS VARCHAR(1)) + CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 10) AS VARCHAR(1)); 

   SET @ID = CONCAT(@randomID,@COUNT); 

   INSERT INTO Table(ID, colB, colC, colD)
   SELECT 
      @ID,
      colB, 
      colC, 
      colD
   FROM #tempTable

   SET @COUNT = @COUNT + 1; 
END
```

Also, i want to generate a concatenated id

¿It is possible to do this with recursive CTE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how you can do it using recursive cte & cross apply:

```
DECLARE @NUM_INSERTS INT;
SET @NUM_INSERTS = 10;

with cte as (
select 1 num
union all
select num+ 1 as num
from cte 
where num < @NUM_INSERTS
)

INSERT INTO Table(ID, colB, colC, colD)
SELECT CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 10) AS VARCHAR(1)) 
       + CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 10) AS VARCHAR(1)) 
       + cte.num as ID
       ,colB,colC,colD
FROM #tempTable
cross apply cte;
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer really helped me out